# Trouble using History.js while reloading page

Tags: jquery, web, history.js

I am using History.js for navigating the user through a menu.

```
Menu            content

home           |-------|   
books          |       |
vidoes         |       |
about          |_______|
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="menu" id="books">Books</div>
<div class="menu" id="videos">Videos</div>
<div class="menu" id="about">About</div>
<div id="container_main_content"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(
function() 
{

// Prepare
var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
if ( !History.enabled ) {
     // History.js is disabled for this browser.
     // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
    return false;
}

// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() 
{ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState();
    console.log(State);
    $.get(State.url,function(data)
        {   
            $("#container_main_content").html("");
            $("#container_main_content").append(data);
        });
});

$('.menu').click(function(evt) 
{
    switch(evt.target.id)
    {
        case "home":History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), "/main/main.php?state="+evt.target.id+"&action=nav");
break;
case "books": History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), "/books/books.php?state="+evt.target.id+"&action=nav");
break;
/*and so on....*/
}
```

The problem is that the url specified in the History.pushState() is just a php script which echoes data sans styling. So when the user reloads the page, the new page has elements arranged haphazardly without any styling. Any suggestions on how to overcome this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My idea: provide full page with layout and appropriate content under these urls. So after visiting directly it displays correctly. And you need "second version" for ajax requests. It can be doneby getting other version for ajax only, e.g. under this url `books.php?state=1&action=nav&ajax=true` Of course push into history this url `books.php?state=1&action=nav` (without ajax variable).

In php do it like so:

```
if($_GET['ajax']!='true') {
    //echo layout head
}

//echo content

if($_GET['ajax']!='true') {
    //echo layout foot
}
```